# tool to remove points from point cloud

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if there is an interactive-marker based tool available that I can use to remove points from a pointcloud or pointcloud2 by clicking on them or highlighting a set of points. Then when the desired pointcloud remains, you can press a key that writes a PCD file. As far as I know, I don't think it would be too hard to write but I'm hoping that it's already available in the object-modeling community. I can see it as a part of the tool chain after you use roboearth to make the model.

If there is no such tool, I would appreciate any advise on quickly cleaning up a PCD file other than just writing a quick program to delete points within a bounding box (guess and check...).

Thanks!

(By the way - if this doesn't exist for point clouds, maybe it exists for other 3D data types such as octomaps? In general, maybe we need a tool that can do this for pointcloud, pointcloud2, octomap, laser scan etc.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53650/tool-to-remove-points-from-point-cloud/) by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 674 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the PCL point cloud editor[1] to load pcd files, select points, delete them, and save the result as pcd.

[1] http://svn.pointclouds.org/pcl/trunk/apps/point_cloud_editor/, see http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/source.html to compile PCL from source ... make sure to set the BUILD_apps and BUILD_app_point_cloud_editor cmake flags to true as they're false by default I think so the app wouldn't get built.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) with karma: 360 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

And there is meshlab. Downside is the conversion of .pcd <-> .ply files.

---

Originally posted by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) with karma: 287 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1